# Does destroying a death totem disable the death protection?

Tags: apex-legends

I've been 'into the shadows' multiple times before, but never has the totem been destroyed while I was in the death protection, so does destroying it disable the death protection?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the Apex Wiki, it doesnt mention about that. https://apexlegends.gamepedia.com/Revenant#Tips

But, it does mention that the Totem can be destroyed, and 'Avoid placing the totem in the open, as it can be easily destroyed.'

I would then guess that if the totem is destroyed while you are in shadow form, the effect will not happen if you do die while in shadow form. So you will simply die.